# How do I do a mean for multiple grouped data in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I'm new to R and I'm trying to get the mean of a data which is sorted by location and treatment.

My data looks like this:

| Wetland | Treatment | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | A | 3 |
| Ann | A | 4 |
| Ann | B | 2 |
| ... |  |  |
| Twin | D | 5 |

I have 9 locations (Wetland) and 4 treatments (Treatment). Each location has 6 data points per treatment. I am trying to get the means of a location and treatment.
Eg:

| Wetland | Treatment | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | A | 3.5 |
| Ann | B | 2 |
| ... |  |  |
| Twin | D | 5 |

I've used

```
aggregate(PlantData$Data, list(PlantData$Wetland),FUN=mean)
```

Which gives me the mean of all the data at the location (`PlantData$Wetland`) but does not separate by treatment.

Comment: A minimum working example with some sample data (in a form R will use) would make it easier for people to answer specifically and correctly. :D

Comment: try `dplyr::group_by(PlantData, Wetland, Treatment) |> dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(Data), .groups = "drop")`

Comment: Sorry, I just finished fixing the formatting issue

Comment: `aggregate(Data~Wetland + Treatment,PlantData, FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: aggregate(Data~Wetland + Treatment,PlantData, FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE) worked. Thank you.